# Separate Compilation and Linking in C++ using Dev-C++

Tags: c++, linker, compiler-errors, dev-c++

Thanks pals for your response so far on my previous post.

I can now do the class things but there is still a stumbling block on my path that I just have to get rid of.

I don’t have any problem with the header file now but the implementation file. The problem is this, if I try to complile the implementation file for my class I do get this error message:

> In function `main':
>
> [Linker error] c:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-svn/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
>
> C:\Users\Chuks Joe\Desktop\myC++Class\collect2.exe       [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

And if I try compiling the main program I get this error messages:

> In function `main':
>
> [Linker error] C:/Users/Chuks Joe/Desktop/carTest.cpp:6: undefined reference to `car::car(float, std::string, std::string)'
>
> [Linker error] C:/Users/Chuks Joe/Desktop/carTest.cpp:8: undefined reference to `car::read_prop() const'
>
> [Linker error] C:/Users/Chuks Joe/Desktop/carTest.cpp:11: undefined reference to `car::change_spd(float)'
>
> [Linker error] C:/Users/Chuks Joe/Desktop/carTest.cpp:14: undefined reference to `car::change_clr(std::string)'
>
> [Linker error] C:/Users/Chuks Joe/Desktop/carTest.cpp:17: undefined reference to `car::read_prop() const'
>
> C:\Users\Chuks Joe\Desktop\collect2.exe      [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

even when I add the code:

```
int main(){}
```

to the implementation file, it compiles without any error message but when I try running the main program, it still gives me the same error message as stated above.

but when I put the main program in the implementation file, it compiles and runs successfully.

Please pals, which of the settings should I review to rectify this issue, because I will prefer my class implementation code to be in a separate file and the main program in another one.

The compiler am using is Dev-C++

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing, but the solution is no doubt simple. You might start by performing a "Build All" and then posting the *complete* build log; that will enable us to see what files are included in your project.  You do need to add *all* the .cpp files to the project.  You talk about "compiling" but are in fact "building" (because the errors are linker errors not compiler errors) - Dev-C++ erroneously has a "Compile" menu that is in fact a build.  Also each separate file is not a *program*; the collection of source files together is a program.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compile both cpp file into executables. You want to compile them to object files though (-c flag for GCC), which are then linked together to form an executable file.

Comment: hi pals, it good now, I can now do the class thing the right way with ma visual studio. am now doing fine with the class. many thanks to you all for your assistance. thanks